# SQLite Exception in android

Tags: android

hi my application contains SQLite .My application some time getting the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.fitzsoftware.grocessaryList/com.fitzsoftware.grocessaryList.GrocessaryList}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to close due to unfinalised statements
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3655)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3673)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to close due to unfinalised statements
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbclose(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.onAllReferencesReleased(SQLiteDatabase.java:320)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.close(SQLiteDatabase.java:881)
at com.fitzsoftware.grocessaryList.GrocessaryList.onDestroy(GrocessaryList.java:103)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3642)
```

I am closing the db in Destroy() using  DataClass.dh.db.close();
Why this Error occured.Give me the solutions for this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh, since it's urgent we'll help you... better?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm late to the party, but I just saw this. In my case, I had created a `Cursor` object from a database query, then accidentally closed the database before I closed the cursor. Check whether this is what's happening.

Comment: Well, I don't know about Pinki, but that was **exactly** what my own problem was :-)

Answer (score 1):

As well Gareth Lloyd's answer, from what I've read of other threads, another cause of this exception is not closing `Cursor` objects, i.e. attempting to close your `SQLiteDatabase` instance before closing `Cursor` objects that have been obtained from querying your `SQLiteDatabase` instance.

Comment: Umm...that's exactly what Gareth Lloyd's answer was.